# Does energy change with change in position of electron (in quantum model)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

In the quantum model of atom, an electron has a probability of being found anywhere in the space (except nodes). Now suppose a first shell electron ($n=1$) is present at a distance $r1$ from the nucleus and has energy $E$. Now if the next instant it is present at a new distance $r2$ from nucleus, will the energy change or remain the same? If no, then why? If yes, then how can we say that principal quantum number determines the energy of the electron? What would be the physical meaning of shell then?

Answer (score 12):

"a first shell electron (n=1) is present at a distance $r_1$ from the nucleus and has energy $E$."

Quantum-mechanically this is impossible. The Hamilton-operator does not commute with  the position operator. So having an electron at energy $E$ and at a known position $r_1$ is impossible.

So of course you could measure the position. But if you do so, the electron will be in a pure position state. However, then the information on the energy state is completely lost. The position state can be decomposed in a series of energy states, and nobody would know in which of these energy states the electron would be. So you can measure the energy state again, but in the very same moment you loose the information of the electron's position ...

This said, it is impossible to know position and energy of an electron at the same time and all speculations about this are make no sense in Quantum mechanics.

Comment: okay....but first tell me what constitutes the total energy of an electron in a QM model

Comment: @user95732 Well, this depends on the circumstances, for instance the potential (harmonic oscillator potential, free electron (no potential), H-atom, He-atom etc). In a H-atom it is $E_n = - \frac{m e^4}{2 (4\pi \epsilon_0)^2  \hbar^2 n^2}$ in SI-units. $n$ is the principal quantum number $n\in \mathbf{N}$

Answer (score 4):

[Here are the hydrogen wave function solutions in space](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html), for (r,θ,φ)

[image]

and further in the link.

The energy of the electron is basically  given by the level of the n quantum number (with some corrections for the spin state), In the simple Bohr model the values are [given here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html), which do not differ from the correct quantum mechanical solution. So the electron in its orbital ( not orbit) has **a probability given by $Ψ^*Ψ$** to be at a particular (r,θ,φ) if measured.

> Now suppose a first shell electron (n=1) is present at a distance 'r1' from the nucleus and has energy E. Now if the next instant it is present at a new distance 'r2' from nucleus, will the energy change or remain the same?

The wavefunction gives only the possibility of calculating probabilities, it is not tied like a quantum number on the electron, that is the misunderstanding. It does not describe where the electron is in space, but just the probability of finding the electron at (r,θ,φ) if measured at an arbitrary time. The energy is always the one characterized by the n quamtum number. It does not change.

To get an idea, look how the orbitals available for electrons in the hydrogen solution look.

[image: orbital]

Comment: But how could the energy remain same if the electron is closer to nucleus? Shouldn't the electrical and gravitational potential energy decrease.....and thus the overall energy?

Comment: @user95732  that is why quantum mechanics had to be invented, to explain the spectra ( transition energies )of atoms which cannot be explained with the classical model you have in mind.

Comment: @user95732 It's time to abandon the notion that the electron exists at some location before measurement. It does not. It's not like the electron is moving around and we just have no idea where it is. Quantum mechanical particles do not have trajectories

Comment: but why does the electron have energy in the first place? isn't it potential energy anc kinetic energy??

Comment: @user95732 When we talk about energy states of the electron, we mean that it is in a state of definite potential energy. i.e. interaction energy with the nucleus. Such states are not states of definite position.

Comment: Why doesn't this potential energy depend on distance from the nucleus?

Comment: @user95732  the Bohr model had the electrons in orbits around the nucleons, classically solving the problem,except that it had to have a quantized angular momentum imposed, so that there would be exact energy levels to fit the spectrum of atoms. If there were no quantization classical theory would have the electron fall on the nucleus and neutralize it, giving a continuous spectrum. the spectra are quantized. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/atspect2.html , not classical expected from your model.

Comment: How does QM explain this? The quantization of spectra

Comment: And I still don't get why does the energy of electron not change with change in distance from nucleus

Comment: because you are stuck in classical mechanics mode. The Bohr model by imposing quantization of angular momentum explained the energy levels , the Balmer and Lyman series. Then quantum mechanics with Schrodingers equations and the wavefunction solutions reproduced the Balmer  etc and Lyman series. You cannot learn quantum mechanics on asking questions, but by studying http://www.physics.gla.ac.uk/~dmiller/lectures/ATS1_2009.pdf

Comment: @annav Part of studying is asking questions. I think it is appropriate to say that the OP needs build a better foundation of QM understanding; I don't think it helps to discourage them from asking questions though.

Answer (score 1):

In a classical framework, the total energy of the electron is its potential energy plus its kinetic energy (although to be precise, the electric potential energy is a property of the entire system, not just the electron). So in the classical model, an electron that's close to the nucleus would have higher velocity than one farther from the nucleus. This only partly translates to the quantum picture, but there is some correspondence for the correctly formulated quantities.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have the other way around, which is the source of your confusion.

From a quantum mechanical standpoint the possible energies are the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian. There really is no other way to look at it. The Hamiltonian is dependent on space is the potential and possibly via interactions.

Thus energies are a functional of space dependent functions, but not coordinate dependent explicitly.

That being said, the converse is true. I.e. the probability of measuring a particle at a certain position depends on is energy.
From a probability point of view the energy and position of a particle are two dependent random variables, drawn from separate distributions.